# TypeLoadError when calling "dotnet exec" under windows server 2016

Tags: c#, .net, typeloadexception

One of my apps is running under my local development machine, but does not under a remote windows 2016 server.

The app is a wpf desktop application which does a "dotnet exec" call that updates a sql server database using a ef core migrations project. As reference here is the command line used:

```
dotnet exec --depsfile ".\MigrationsTest.deps.json" --additionalProbingPath "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder" --additionalProbingPath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages" --runtimeconfig "MigrationsTest.runtimeconfig.json" "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.entityframeworkcore.tools\2.2.0\tools\netcoreapp2.0\any\ef.dll" database drop -f --assembly ".\MigrationsTest" --startup-assembly ".\MigrationsTest" --project-dir . --verbose --root-namespace MigrationsTest --context DbContextAuth
```

The error I receive is the following:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.ForwardingProxy.Unwrap[T](Object target)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor..ctor(Object reportHandler, IDictionary args)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.ReflectionOperationExecutor..ctor(String assembly, String startupAssembly, String projectDir, String dataDirectory, String rootNamespace, String language)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Commands.ProjectCommandBase.CreateExecutor()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Commands.DatabaseDropCommand.Execute()
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.CommandLine.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Program.Main(String[] args)
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
```

I already used fuslogvw but there no problems are displayed.

My local configuration is:

- Windows 10 Pro
- Version 1809
- .Net Framework 4.7.2
- SDK 2.2.3

My target configuration is:

- Windows Server 2016
- .Net Framework 4.7.2, tried 4.8 but same result
- SDK 2.2.3

Both systems are part of the same domain

Any clue how I can determine why the TypeLoad fails?

Comment: I'm confused, you're using .NET Core CLI to run a non-.NET Core app?

Comment: MigrationsTest is a NetCore 2.2 Console appiication